# Find Address of Windows Kernel Functions

Tags: windows, debuggers

How can I find the address of a Windows kernel function?

In this case I'm trying to find CreateThread.

Can this be done from a debugger? Olly/Immunity?

Comment: if you mean CreateThread in kernel32.dll with ollydbg 2.01 alt +e ->right click show names in all modules start typing CreateThread and double click the resultant line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done programmatically with a combination of `NtQuerySystemInformation`, `LoadLibraryEx`, and `GetProcAddress`.

The code below may not work perfectly, as I don't have a Windows box to build it for testing.  However, it should move you in the correct direction.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

enum { SystemModuleInformation = 11 };

typedef struct _RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION {
    ULONG Section;
    PVOID MappedBase;
    PVOID ImageBase;
    ULONG ImageSize;
    ULONG Flags;
    USHORT LoadOrderIndex;
    USHORT InitOrderIndex;
    USHORT LoadCount;
    USHORT OffsetToFileName;
    CHAR FullPathName[256];
} RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION, *PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _RTL_PROCESS_MODULES {
    ULONG NumberOfModules;
    RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION Modules[1];
} RTL_PROCESS_MODULES, *PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES;

typedef NTSTATUS (*NtQuerySystemInformationFunc)(
    _In_      DWORD SystemInformationClass,
    _Inout_   PVOID                    SystemInformation,
    _In_      ULONG                    SystemInformationLength,
    _Out_opt_ PULONG                   ReturnLength
);

ULONG64 GetKernelFunctionAddress(LPCSTR Name) {
    NtQuerySystemInformationFunc NtQuerySystemInformation = NULL;
    HMODULE hKernel = NULL;
    HMODULE hNtdll = NULL;
    ULONG64 KernelBase = NULL;
    ULONG64 KernelFunctionAddress = NULL;
    RTL_PROCESS_MODULES ModuleInfo = { 0 };

    // Get the address of NtQuerySystemInformation
    hNtdll = GetModuleHandle("ntdll");
    NtQuerySystemInformation = (NtQuerySystemInformationFunc)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    // Get the base address of the kernel
    NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, &ModuleInfo, sizeof(ModuleInfo), NULL);
    KernelBase = (ULONG64)ModuleInfo.Modules[0].ImageBase;

    // Load the kernel
    hKernel = LoadLibraryEx(strrchr(ModuleInfo.Modules[0].FullPathName, '\\') + 1, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);

    // Look up the function in the kernel
    KernelFunctionAddress = (ULONG64)GetProcAddress(hKernel, Name);

    // Adjust the address based on the kernel load address
    KernelFunctionAddress -= (ULONG64)hKernel;
    KernelFunctionAddress += KernelBase;

    return KernelFunctionAddress;
}
```

Comment: Smart approach! Even though I gave a different answer, I voted yours up ;)

Comment: No need to dynamically import NtQuerySystemInformation, it is defined in winternl.h, though not all SystemInformationClass values are defined. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation

Answer (score 5):

From WinDbg you can use the [`x`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561506.aspx) command.

For example:

```
kd> x nt!NtCreateThread
830e4fda          nt!NtCreateThread (<no parameter info>)
```

When I lookup the address for the `NtCreateThread` function above, WinDbg tells me that `NtCreateThread` is at address `0x830e4fda`.

(You'd probably want to use [LiveKd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/livekd.aspx) instead as it's easier than hooking up a remote kernel debugger.)

Comment: beat me to it! dont forget, if youre trying to trap a native API call which would be better for hooking or introspection, you'd want to use

    x ntdll!ZwCreateThread

Answer (score 0):

In Ollydbg you can select the disassembly windows and hit `CTRL + g`. A dialog box will show up and just enter `CreateThread` in it. The search is case sensitive.

**EDIT**

This does not work for Windows Kernel functions but it does work for any function from a DLL that is imported by the program being debugged. Since you are searching for `CreateThread` address, I assume that is what you meant from your question.

Comment: This won't work for Windows kernel functions. OllyDbg does not have access to the kernel's address space.

Comment: @JasonGeffner you are right! I mixed the terminology since I only saw that the OP was looking for address of a common DLL function. The answer has beed edited.